# How to define persistent variable in SQL*PLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to do the following in `SQL*PLUS` in `ORACLE`.

- Create a variable
- Pass it as output variable to my method invocation
- Print the value from output variable

I get

> *undeclared variable*

error. I am trying to create a variable that persists in the session till i close the `SQL*PLUS` window.

```
variable subhandle number;
exec MYMETHOD - (CHANGE_SET => 'SYNC_SET', - DESCRIPTION => 'Change data for emp', 
                                           - SUBSCRIPTION_HANDLE => :subhandle);

print subhandle;
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be OK - check what you did carefully against this:

```
SQL> create procedure myproc (p1 out number)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4     p1 := 42;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> variable subhandle number
SQL> exec myproc(:subhandle)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print subhandle

 SUBHANDLE
----------
        42
```

Answer (score 0):

Please can you re-post, but formatting the code with the code tag.... (ie the 101 010 button)  I think some extra "-" characters came through which means it more difficult to interpret.

Might also be helpful to see SQL*Plus reporting the error if you could copy the contents of the SQL*Plus window instead/too?

But it looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but did you try the `&&variable` syntax?  You could do

```
select &&subhandle from dual
```

or some such at the start of the script, then `subhandle` should be bound to that value for the remainder of the session.